# Allow reading during an SQL transaction?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In my website, I have a calendar of events:

[image]

Now you will notice  they are well organized into days.

This is a function used by administrators to organize projects.

Here is the problem.

While this happens, I use a transaction scope since it modifies multiple events and could fail:

ex:

```
 //needs id '9999'
public string Explode()
{
   string eid = Request.Form["id"];

   using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new System.TimeSpan(2, 45, 0)))
            {
   try
   {
      int id = int.Parse(eid);

      Project p = ProjectManager.GetProject(id);
      int resID = p.Schedule.Employee.EmployeID;
      Employee e = ResourceManager.GetEmployee(resID);
      if (e == null)
         throw new Exception();

      var tasks = ProjectManager.GetProjectTasks(id);
      var ordered = SyncManager.Instance.GetTasks((int)p.PaymoID);

      Task firstTask = null;

      foreach (Paymo.Task t in ordered)
      {
         Task tsk = (from obj in tasks where obj.PaymoID != null && obj.PaymoID.Value == t.ID select obj).FirstOrDefault();
         if (tsk != null && t.UserName == e.EmployeName
            && tsk.Schedule == null)
         {
            if (firstTask == null)
            {
               firstTask = tsk;
            }

            int scheduleID = ScheduleManager.CreateSchedule(p.Schedule.DateFrom.Value
               ,t.BudgetHours <= 0 ? 1.0M : t.BudgetHours , e.EmployeID);

            if (scheduleID == -1)
               throw new Exception();

            if (!ScheduleManager.ChangeTaskSchedule(tsk.TaskID, scheduleID))
               throw new Exception();

            if (!ScheduleManager.GiveLowestPriority(ScheduleManager.GetSchedule(scheduleID)))
            {
               throw new Exception();
            }                           
          }
       }

       ScheduleManager.ChangeProjectSchedule(p.ProjectID, null);
       if (firstTask != null)
       {
          Bump b = new Bump();
          b.DoBump(firstTask.Schedule);
       }
       scope.Complete();
    }

    catch (Exception)
    {
       return "fail";
    }
  } 
  return "";
}
```

Now the problem is, while the transaction is happening, If a user tries to access the calendar in read only mode, they have to wait before they see it.

Is there some way that the web site could still load during a transaction?
I use LINQ SQL and SQL Server 2008 and VS 2012.

Comment: Well I have no idea what ridiculous limitations LINQ might place on this strategy, but you can perform your reads using read committed snapshot isolation, which will prevent them from being blocked by writers - assuming that's what you want. If someone is making a change to the schedule, is it ok for the reader to see the pre-change version, or do you want them to wait for the update?

Comment: It is okay for them to see the prechange version... I do not want them to have to wait...

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question by @AaronBertrand. Clearly you don't want them to wait - but do you want them to be able to read the pre-chagned version (i.e. a dirty read albeit reversed :D)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your using to:

```
new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TransactionOptions() { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted,Timeout = new System.TimeSpan(2, 45, 0) }));
```